# Is aggregation (count) on dimension but not on metrics supported by Druid

Tags: java, sql, database, olap, druid

For example there are **two dimensions: [country, website]** and **one metric: [PV].**

I want to know the average PV of website for each country.

To make it, it's easy to get **the total PV in each country**, however it's difficult to get the **count of website in each country**, furthermore the expect result is **the total PV(in each country) divided by the count of website(in each country)**.

What I can do is apply "groupBy" query by country & website as below, and then group the result by country outside in my application. **It's very very very slow**, because the query extract lots of data from Druid and most of them is meaningless just for a sum.

```
{
    "queryType": "groupBy",
    "dataSource": "--",
    "dimensions": [
        "country",
        "website"
    ],
    "granularity": "all",
    "intervals": [
        "--"
    ],
    "aggregations": [
        {
            "type": "longSum",
            "name": "PV",
            "fieldName": "PV"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any one can help with this? I'm wondering it's impossible such a common query is not supported by Druid.

Thanks in advance.

---

---

To be clear, I describe my expected result by SQL, if you have known what I want to do or not familiar to SQL, please ignore the following part.

```
SELECT country, sum(a.PV_all) / count(a.website) as PV_AVG FROM
(SELECT country, website, SUM(PV) as PV_all FROM DB GROUP BY country, website  ) a
GROUP BY country
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a nested groupBy query ? druid support that.
In nutshell you can have something like

```
{
  "queryType": "groupBy",
  "dataSource":{
    "type": "query",
    "query": {
      "queryType": "groupBy",
      "dataSource": "yourDataSource",
      "granularity": "--",
      "dimensions": ["country", "website"],
      "aggregations": [
        {
            "type": "longSum",
            "name": "PV",
            "fieldName": "PV"
        }
      ],
      "intervals": [ "2012-01-01T00:00:00.000/2020-01-03T00:00:00.000" ]
    }
  },
  "granularity": "all",
  "dimensions": ["country"],
  "aggregations": [
    ----
  ],
  "intervals": [ "2012-01-01T00:00:00.000/2020-01-03T00:00:00.000" ]
}
```